# Close lingering connection

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using python-requests for a client tool. It makes repeated requests to servers at an interval. However if the server disconnects, the client fails with a socket error on its next request. It appears the client is keeping the connection open from its side, rather than reconnecting. These connections could be hours apart, so it is unlikely the server wouldn't disconnect it.

Is there a way to override keep alive and force it to close? Is there something similar to:

```
with requests.get(url) as r:
  doStuff(r)
# R is cleaned up, the socket is closed.
```

that would force the connection to clean up after I'm done?

As written that doesn't work, because requests.Response doesn't have an __ exit__ call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

I haven't tested it, based only on the API doc:

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url)
doStuff(r)
s.close()
```

Or, to make sure that the close is always called, even if there's an exception, here's how to emulate the with-statement using a try/finally:

```
s = requests.Session()
try:
    r = s.get(url)
    doStuff(r)
finally:
    s.close()
```

Comment: +1. Or, you could actually _use_ a with statement: `with contextlib.closing(s):`.